# C# get_Resize(910000, 3) exception while adding data to excel

Tags: c#, excel, office365

i  am getting following exception "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" while adding array data to excel. I am only getting this error when first paramter passed is greater than "90000" "get_Resize(900000, 3)". Does any one know how to store data with thousands of records to excel file.Below is my code.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook worKbooK;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range celLrangE;


        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // excel.Visible = false;
        //excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

        worKbooK = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)worKbooK.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "StudentRepoertCard";



        object[,] objData = new Object[900000, 3];
        Random rdm = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        double nOrderAmt, nTax;
        for (int r = 0; r < 900000; r++)
        {
            objData[r, 0] = "ORD" + r.ToString("0000");
            nOrderAmt = 2;
            objData[r, 1] = nOrderAmt.ToString("c");
            nTax = nOrderAmt * 0.07;
            objData[r, 2] = nTax.ToString("c");
        }
        // int 
        //   String A2 = "A" + objData.Length.ToString();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range m_objRange = worksheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
        m_objRange = m_objRange.get_Resize(900000, 3);
        m_objRange.Value = objData;

       
        m_objRange = worksheet.get_Range("A910000", Missing.Value);

        m_objRange = m_objRange.get_Resize(910000, 3);
        m_objRange.Value = objData;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a library like EPPlus to form the excel file directly, rather than using interop? Running an entire program and poking it to do stuff, just to create an xml file inside a zip file is definitely a clunky way to do things(and you need to have a licensed excel installed)

Comment: @CaiusJard I have used ADO.Net as well but not EPPlus. I think i have to pay to use that for commercial use.

Comment: Why would *you* have to pay for commercial use? The company pays, no? Which means the customer pays.. and because the customer is getting the utility from what you create they get the value. Otherwise they have to pay for excel.. Tell me something else: Do you expect to be be paid for the work you do, so you can pay your bills, feed and clothe yourself..? Is the same not true for the EPPlus developer? We use libraries to do stuff because we recognize that the small cost of the library is *good value for money*. The cost doesn't have to be 0 to enable this. Never confuse cost with value